# Google Cloud Bucket mounted on Compute Engine Instance using gcsfuse does not create files

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, mount, gcsfuse

I have been able to mount Google Cloud Bucket using

```
gcsfuse --implicit-dirs " production-xxx-appspot /mount
```

or equally

```
sudo mount -t gcsfuse -o implicit_dirs,allow_other,uid=1000,gid=1000,key_file=service-account.json production-xxx-appspot /mount
```

Mounting works fine.

What happens is that when I execute the following commands after mounting, they also work fine :

```
mkdir /mount/files/
cp -rf /home/files/* /mount/files/
```

However, when I use :

```
mcedit /mount/files/a.txt
```

or

```
vi /mount/files/a.txt
```

The output says that there is no file available which makes sense.

Is there any other way to cover this situation, and use applications in a way that they can directly create files on the mounted google cloud bucket rather than creating files locally and copying afterwards.

Comment: Check the Compute Engine scopes (edit the instance in the Google Cloud Web GUI. Your VM probably only has the scope for Cloud Storage READ. Click the enable WRITE option. You must shutdown the instance to make changes, but you can check the settings while the instance is running.

Comment: It says " Storage Read/Write" on the VM Instance in web UI. I can create directories and even copy files to google cloud storage. But for instance when I use an application such as MP4Box or mcedit or vi, it cannot create or use the files as they do not exist yet.

Comment: What do you mean by "the do not exist yet"? Are you referring to caching as in you are creating a file on one system and not seeing on another system?

Comment: "as do not exist yet" means that, for instance, a text editor tries to open a file on a mounted google cloud bucket. It cannot do that and return an error saying that "the file cannot be opened". But with same mounted bucket, I can create directories and copy files from other mounted drives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to create files locally and upload later, you should consider using a file storage system like [Google Drive](https://www.google.com/drive/)

Google Cloud storage is an object Storage system that means objects cannot be modified, you have to write the object completely at once. Object storage also does not work well with traditional databases, because writing objects is a slow process and writing an app to use an object storage API is not as simple as using file storage.

In a [file storage system](https://cloud.google.com/filestore), Data is stored as a single piece of information inside a folder, just like you would organize pieces of paper inside a manila folder. When you need to access that piece of data, your computer needs to know the path to find it. (Beware—It can be a long, winding path.)

If you want to use Google Cloud Storage, you need to create your file locally and then push it to your bucket.

Here are an example of how to [configure Google Cloud Storage with Node.js: File Upload example](https://www.bezkoder.com/google-cloud-storage-nodejs-upload-file/)

Here is a tutorial on How to [mount Object Storage on Cloud Server using s3fs-fuse](https://upcloud.com/community/tutorials/mount-object-storage-cloud-server-s3fs-fuse/)

If you want to know more about storage formats please [follow this link](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/data-storage/file-block-object-storage)

More information about reading and writing to Cloud Storage [in this link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage)